# x axis on c3 chart shows only first and last value

Tags: javascript, graph, c3.js

I'm using c3 chart for js. My code is below:

```
c3.generate({
        bindto:'#someChart',
        data: {
            columns: [
                data
            ]
        },
        axis: {
            x : {
                type: 'categories',
                categories:categories,
                tick:{
                    count: 12
                }
            }
        },
        point:{
            show:false
        }
    });
```

I have one problem. On x axis is showed only first and last value(12th).

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in c3 where if the tick is due to occur at a fractional x value (i.e. the number of ticks means it should pop up say every 2.06666 categories) then it doesn't render --> https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1638

There's a fix that's offered there to run before you generate your chart -->

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.categoryName = function (i) {
    var config = this.config, categoryIndex = Math.ceil(i);
    return i < config.axis_x_categories.length ? config.axis_x_categories[categoryIndex] : i;
};
```

But I find while it now shows the right number of ticks, it often still doesn't line up the labels and ticks nicely to the data points (they're positioned partway in between).

On that point, it's better, if you can, to set the number of ticks (-1) to divide without a fraction into the number of data points (-1) you're wanting to show and they'll both avoid your initial issue and line up nicely.

e.g. (datapoints - 1)/(no.of.ticks - 1) == whole number